Stripe error in symfony: REQUES Uncaught PHP Exception Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException: "Not a valid URL"
I created this code in symfony:
    #[Route('/buy/{subjectId}', name: 'buy_subject', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function buySubject(Request $request, $subjectId, ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry, $stripeSK): Response
    {
        $entityManager = $managerRegistry->getManager();
        $subject = $entityManager->getRepository(Subject::class)->find($subjectId);
    
        error_log('Subject ID: ' . $subjectId);
    
        if (!$subject) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Subject not found');
        }
    
        dump($subject);
    
        Stripe::setApiKey($stripeSK);
    
        error_log('Stripe API Key: ' . $stripeSK);
    
        $totalAmount = $subject->getSubjectPrice() ;
    
        error_log('Total Amount: ' . $totalAmount);
    
        $checkoutSession = Session::create([
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'line_items' => [[
                'price_data' => [
                    'currency' => 'usd',
                    'product_data' => [
                        'name' => $subject->getSubjectName(),
                    ],
                    'unit_amount' => $totalAmount,
                ],
                'quantity' => 1,
            ]],
            'mode' => 'payment',
            'success_url' => $this->generateUrl('subject_success'),
            'cancel_url' => $this->generateUrl('subject_cancel'),  
        ]);
    
    
        return $this->redirect($checkoutSession->url, 303);
    } 

Only to get this error:

[Application] Apr 30 23:52:43 |CRITICA| REQUES Uncaught PHP Exception
Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException: "Not a valid URL" at
C:\Users\user\Downloads\TW2.0-Starter-Project-main\vendor\stripe\stripe-php\lib\Exception\ApiErrorException.php
line 38

I expected the click on the Buy button to take me to the stripe checkout page

Because generated urls with generateUrl by your implementation does not return absolute URL only absolute path.
You need to pass third parameter to generate absolute URL
$this->generateUrl('subject_success', [], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
Duplicate: How can I fix this Stripe error in symfony?
